# Pass multiple data type in Helm-chart value properties

Tags: kubernetes-helm

values.yml

```
envconfig:
  key1: val1
  key2: val2
  key3: ["val3", "val4"]
  key5: val5
```

template attempted:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.envconfig }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $val | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Expected output:

```
$key1 = val1
$key2 = val2
$key3 = ["val3", "val4"]
$key5 = val5
```

output that I got:

```
$key1 = val1
$key2 = val2
$key3 = [val3
$key5 = val5
```

Any suggestions how to fix this by handling multiple data types (integer, string, and list in this case) in the template?

Comment: Helm [includes](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) `toYaml` and `toJson` functions, which might be part of an answer; what data do you want to be in the ConfigMap for list-valued `key3`?

Comment: Please give your expected output

Comment: Updated the question. please check now.